# is it possible to merge a twitter and facebook feed into a single feed?

Tags: facebook, twitter

Is it possible to merge a twitter and facebook status feeds into a single feed to display on a website?

Comment: Hi, Sean. You're going to have to narrow the scope of this question or it will likely get voted down and closed. Show us some code that you've tried or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is you could use Yahoo pipes which was built for this.

Check out [this pipe](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=7Jqm__RE3BGGJIWUyjUFzw) for an [example](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.edit?_id=7Jqm__RE3BGGJIWUyjUFzw):

> Combine your facebook status with blog feeds, news searches, twitter,
>   last.fm flickr and youtube.